# Loop through worksheet names and if exists...run macro

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to combine a number of macros into one.

There may not always be the same number of worksheets and therefore not all macros are necessary.
Therefore i was trying to have a "if worksheet exists" check before executing. But unfortunately it seems to loop back again to the second macro, which has already executed, and therfore fails.

```
Sub Add_ALL_Totals()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Add_OPT1_Totals_inc_WFE

For Each ws In Worksheets

If ws.Name Like "*OPT2*" Then
Add_OPT2_Totals ' run this macro

End If
If ws.Name Like "*OPT3*" Then

Add_OPT3_Totals ' run this macro
End If
If ws.Name Like "*OPT4*" Then
Add_OPT4_Totals ' run this macro
End If
If ws.Name Like "*OPT5*" Then
Add_OPT5_Totals ' run this macro
End If
If ws.Name Like "*OPT6*" Then
Add_OPT6_Totals ' run this macro
End If

Next ws
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a function to check if sheet exists:

```
Public Function SheetExists(ByVal SheetName As String) As Boolean

Dim i As Integer
With ActiveWorkbook
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name = SheetName Then
            SheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    SheetExists = False
End With

End Function
```